# Mounting usb device by hardware port using autofs under Ubuntu via executable map

Tags: usb, mount, autofs

I am trying to mount a usb storage device, plugged at a specific port of my pc to a defined location under Ubuntu. Its supposed to mount every device which was plugged at exactly this port to there and it should do this during runtime of the system.

I found “autofs” as a tool which should be able to do this. However, I couldn’t mount to a specific port on the device, just to the UUID and the registration in Ubuntu (/dev/sda1 for example)

I circumvented this by making a bash out of the map file. Which now generates a string with the UUID of the disk at the specific port.

Here is what I did:

created an target dir `sudo mkdir /automnt`

add to this file `/etc/auto.master` my map by adding the line:
`/automnt /etc/auto.automnt --timeout=5 --ghost`

creating a map file called `/etc/auto.automnt`

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "-fstype=vfat,sync :/dev/disk/by-uuid/398512B2202AD81F"
```

Note: for the stake of simplicity, I tried to debug with the UUID directly here since creating this string is working and not part of my question.

So far so good but now the confusion starts: When making a non bash map file it would look like this:

```
/automnt/stick -fstype=vfat,sync :/dev/disk/by-uuid/398512B2202AD81F
```

Where in the front it states the sub folder to which the usb device gets mounted. However, when making it an executable map it just works when returning the string without.

When researching this I found the following answer:

> "A program map will be called with the key as an argument."

[link to source](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man5/autofs.5.html)

The key to my understanding is the mount point. However where is this coming from? And how can I, using the map file as a scrip, define where its going to mount?

What I tried previously but it wasn't working either is to use the hardware port directly in a static map via:

```
/automnt/stick -fstype=vfat,sync :/dev/disk/by-path/pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:5:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0-part1
```

However I could not get it working.

Thank you for helping :-)